# Use of "for loop" in conjunction with lists in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

The following code does not execute the for loop for whole size of the list.

The code takes number of players (n) and their score in a list and finds out the SECOND RUNNER UP.

size of list : `n`

list name : `arr`

```
n = int(input())

arr = list(map(int, input().split()))

maximum = max(arr)

print(maximum)

arr.remove(maximum)

for i in arr:

    if i == maximum:
        arr.remove(maximum)

        print(arr)

    else:

        print("second runner up ", i)

print(max(i))
```

example:

```
n : 10
arr: 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 1
```

output : `1`

Comment: You can just avoid removal: second = None; for i in l: if second is None or second < i < maximum: second = i Alternatively you can use a comprehension max( (i for i in l if i<max)) for a oneliner

Answer (score -1):

```
n = int(input())

arr = list(map(int, input().split()))

maximum = max(arr)

print(maximum)

arr.remove(maximum)

for i in arr:

    if i == maximum:
        arr.remove(maximum)

        print(arr)

else:

    print("second runner up ", i)

    print(max(i))
```

make sure you put tab in front of your else statement

```
n = int(input())

arr = list(map(int, input().split()))

maximum = max(arr)

print(maximum)

arr.remove(maximum)

for i in arr:

    if i == maximum:
        arr.remove(maximum)

        print(arr)

    else:

        print("second runner up ", i)

        print(max(i))
```

Comment: a) the result would not return the second runner up but all != max b) use spaces not tabs